# AS3 TextChange Event?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, textbox, textchanged

I just want to know if there is any TextChange Event or equivalent to that in AS3? I am currently using Adobe Flash CS3 with my AS3 files and I have to detect whether or not my TextTool's value has changed or not.

With my data being integers ranging from -4.440 to 3.560, I obviously cannot use the `!=` operator.

If anyone knows how to achieve this on integers, please let me know. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same is in Flash too, just use addEventListener to your text component:

`

```
        import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

        protected function textinput1_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
        {
            var digit:Number=new Number((event.currentTarget as TextInput).text);
            if(digit!=NaN)
                Alert.show(digit.toString());//do what you want

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextInput change="textinput1_changeHandler(event)"/>
```

`

Comment: thanks for this. i've only been using AS3 for the past 2 months and so i'm basically new to it. never knew such events exist! thanks!